# Same thumbnail in all posts of my blogger

Tags: blogger

I want to show same thumbnail in all my blogs. So in every post I have to edit its html by img style="display:none;" which I dont like. so is there any option that same thumbnail should appear in all post automatically without editing their html?

Comment: Please give more details if your website is WordPress powered, dynamic or static, because the way it sounds, you have your pages as .html (static) and not .php (dynamic).  If you have a dynamic website, you may prepare some template for your blog posting section with the thumbnail.  You can call with php e.g.  <?php  require("your-template-location-folder/posting-page.php"); ?>  
  Every time a new posting is created, that will 'call' the same and you do not need to go one-by-one changing the default. Any changes to your template, you just do once. Hope this gives some insight.

Comment: The user has tagged the question with Blogger - I'd assume that is the platform being used.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to edit the template, so that that the desired image with  img style="display:none;" applied is included immediately after your post header lines, in the post-body content div but before the actual content.    Howerver I've not tried this, and don't know whether Blogger would pick up the thumbnail from an image outside of the post-body content or not.

Other than that, what you want is not possible in Blogger.